# Css grid/flex in pdf

Tags: html, css, laravel, pdf, laravel-snappy

I use barryvdh/laravel-snappy to generate pdf and need to create a signature area in my pdf doc. There must be two signature fields because it's a contract pdf but when I use css grid or flex they place one under the other. How to place them side by side?

```html
 <div class="flex-container" style="  display:flex;                    
                    padding: 10px;">
            <div class="flex-item" style="padding: 20px; text-align: center;">
                <h2 style="text-decoration:underline">sign1</h2>                
            </div>
            <div class="flex-item"  style="padding: 20px; text-align: center;">
                <h2 style="text-decoration:underline">sign2</h2>
            </div>                    
    </div>
```

Comment: Is flex and grid supported by it? Most pdf generators do not support it I have worked with.

Comment: It does not support so I ask that is there an alternative way to put two field side by side

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/ecp0ytr2/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<div class="flex-container" style=" margin: auto; display:table;                    
                    padding: 10px;border:1px solid red">
            <div class="flex-item" style="padding: 20px; text-align: center;background-color: blue; display: table-cell">
                <h2 style="text-decoration:underline">sign1</h2>                
            </div>
            <div class="flex-item"  style=" margin: auto; padding: 20px; text-align: center;background-color: green; display:table-cell">
                <h2 style="text-decoration:underline">sign2</h2>
            </div>                    
    </div>
```

True, I tried to convert HTML with flex to PDF. The two containers go on two lines. My advice is to use 'display:table' to '.flex-container' and 'display: table-cell' to '.flex-item. That worked out for me.